# TA12-100 Current Sensor (increase range)

Tags: sensor, current-measurement

I have a TA12-100 current sensor. The circuit have a 200ohm resistor as shown below. At 5A the analog signal hits the roof (1023).
My question is - can I increase the resistor to be able to get readings up to 10A(with some lower accuracy I assume)?

[image: Circuit diagram]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It’s the opposite. You need to *decrease* the resistor to increase the range, up to a point.

The resistor loads the output winding of the transformer and is reflected back into the circuit reduced by the square of the turns ratio. A smaller resistor is equivalent to a smaller resistance in series with your load.

However, if there is a metal/ferrite core in this sensor (I believe there is) this core will saturate with higher currents (particularly any DC component which it does not measure). So make sure not to exceed the current specification of the sensor.

Answer (score 0):

We generally respect a "Spec sheet" (below). It is designed for 5 amps maximum, not 10 amps.

You claim that this sensor is *too sensitive*, putting out a signal that overloads your Arduino analog-to-digital converter. You would **decrease** the 200 ohm resistor value in order to decrease sensitivity.
[image: spec sheet for current sensor]